# Present JSON data as link

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

The data is retrieved from the database then encoded into JSON data, then passed into the view:

```
 $json_data = json_encode(array('questions' => $x));      
 $search_results['search_results'] = $json_data;
 $this->load->view('findquestions',$search_results);
```

which looks like:

```
{"questions":[{"question_title":"java"},{"question_title":"big java book"}]}
```

How can the "question_title"s then be presented as separate links?

Does json_decode need to be used, then what

Comment: once you decode json, then it's a native data structure: a string, an array, an object, an integer, blah blah blah blah. Use that like you would any OTHER native structure. In your case, you'll get (most likely) an object containing an array of objects.

Comment: Code Ignighter uses php as it's templating language in the view, meaning there is no need to json encode your data unless you are passing it raw to javascript.

Comment: @Marc B ok so I can just use a for each loop etc?